# Are there algorithms available to draw a straight line in 3D space based on WGS 84 points?

Tags: wgs84, computational-geometry

Given

- two points (A,B) defined in the WGS 84 system - i.e. each with their own Lat-Long-Alt coordinate
- the plane T tangent to the WGS84 ellipsoid at point A

is there an algorithm/formula to compute, still within the WGS 84 system

- the plane P containing the two points and perpendicular to the given tangent plane T
- a line L going through A within plane P with an arbitrary angle w.r.t. T?